# How to parse tree with all nodes(caption + link) by anglesharp

Tags: c#, html-parsing, anglesharp

how i can parse topic nodes in [this html code](https://1fichier.com/?eejpbvsxg0) and grab all topics nodes(with their captions and links) and finally show in the treeView?

[image: ...]

im newbie in the angleSharp.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with "in the treeview", but I will ignore this domain specific part and tell you how to get some nodes etc. (by the way: the page you referenced seems to be outdated / wrong - please add the particular code snippet to your question if you want to have it properly answered).

For simplicity I am assuming an HTML like

```
<body>
  <... some_nesting>
    <div class="topic-class">
      <h2>Topic Title</h2>
      <... some_nesting>
        <div class="category-class">
          <h3>Category Title</h3>
          <... some_nesting>
            <a href="caption-link" class="caption-class">Caption Title</a>
          </...>
          <more ... />
        </div>
        <more ... />
      </...>
    </div>
    <more ... />
  </...>
</body>
```

Now we need to work on two things:

1. What we look for (identify tags & structure)
2. How we want to group our findings (map hierarchy)

In the simple HTML we easily identify CSS classes as identifiers (e.g., `.topic-class`, `.category-class`, `.caption-link`), especially in combination with the given structure and tags. Regarding the grouping we need to go from topic to category to caption.

All in all we can write more concise LINQ or more explicit readable code to yield the grouping structure. For illustration purposes I go for the latter:

```
// document is current document returned from OpenAsync of an IBrowsingContext instance
var topics = document.QuerySelectorAll("body > .topic-class");

foreach (var topic in topics)
{
    var topicTitle = topic.QuerySelector("h2")?.TextContent;
    var categories = topic.QuerySelectorAll(".category-class");

    foreach (var category of categories)
    {
        var categoryTitle = category.QuerySelector("h3")?.TextContent;
        var captions = category.QuerySelectorAll("a.caption-link");

        foreach (IHtmlAnchorElement caption of captions)
        {
            var captionTitle = caption.TextContent;
            var link = caption.Href;
        }
    }
}
```

What's left here is appending the topics, categories, and captions to a proper data container for displaying it. But all the information is there, you just need to know how you want to use / model it.

Hope this helps!